# Create interactive report from Rmarkdown shiny app and open it in browser from a bash script

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Background: I have a Rmarkdown document to create a report about a dataset. This (static) report is, via a bash script which calls R, created as a pdf or an html. This uses `rmarkdown::render()` and works nicely.

Now I would like to use an interactive report (i.e. RMarkdown shiny app). what I would like to have is that I call a bask script and the dynamic report is created and opened in a browser. But I do not manage it and I also can not find any documentation about this.

Can anybody help and provide any help?

I know I could write a shiny app, but in this context, an Rmarkdown shiny app would be much easier to create and modify when needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use `rmarkdown::run` instead of `rmarkdown::render`.

```
?rmarkdown::run
```

> Start a Shiny server for the given document, and render it for
> display.